# PowerShell hiding GPU from process

Tags: powershell, gpu

I start graphic multiple render processes using Powershell. Sometimes several render processes try to use the GPU and this causes problems. Is there a way to disable or hide the GPU before starting a process? Like > disable GPU for next process > run process > enable/unhide GPU

Thanks,
Wim

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem of inter-process resource allocation.
Hiding a GPU is not the solution, and is probably impossible in any case.
You should rather use a synchronization element like
[semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)
or
[mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)
(mutual exclusion).

Here is an example of using a mutex:

```
$mutex = new-object System.Threading.Mutex $false,'SomeUniqueName'
...
$mutex.WaitOne() > $null
...
$mutex.ReleaseMutex()
```

A detailed example can be found in the article
[Using Mutexes to Write Data to the Same Logfile Across Processes With PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/).